# wxPython: MenuBar Bound Events Execute on Init

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Hello StackOverflow Hive Mind;

I am in the process of learning how to use wxPython it make a GUI for an application I am writing. I've been slogging through that well enough until I noticed that I could not properly make a menu bar. Whatever I am doing wrong is causing my event bindings to be executed upon the running of the program. Here is the code in question. Minor misspellings should be ignored, I am retyping this off of my development machine which is offline so I might miss a key here or there.

```
def onDocClick():
   message = wx.MessageBox("did it work?","Question",wx.YES_NO)

def onAboutClick():
   pass

frame = wx.Frame(parent=None,title="RVR GUI",size=(315,490))
frame.Show()
panel = wx.Panel(frame,-1,size=(315,490)

menubar = wx.MenuBar()
fileMenu = wx.Menu()
documentation = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW,"Documentation")
about = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"About")
menuBar.Append(fileMenu,'File')

frame.SetMenuBar(menubar)
menubar.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,onDocClick(),documentation)
menubar.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,onAboutClick(),about)
```

There is alot more to the GUI than that but the rest of the code works fine so I don't think you need it. Basically what is happening, is that the message box in onDocClick() is executed as soon as I run the script that opens the GUI. One I click amy button the rest of the GUI initializes fine and a click on the "Documentation" menu entry sees absolutly nothin at all happen. I have a feeling I am probobly missing something simple, perhaps wx.EVT_MENU is not the right one to use in this situation? If that is the case what would the right one to use be? Every single tutorial I have seen on wxPython has done it this way without explaination. Honestly I have been appalled at the lack of meaningful documentation for wxPython. The Zetcode tutorials and even the ever helpful Mouse vs Python just seems to glaze right over the fundamentals of how the toolkit works. But I digress and I've been making do, I've just been completely befuddled by this. Anyway thanks and I appreciate any responses!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a really close look at your code. I think you are doing everything alright in terms of using wxPython, but the event binding is not done properly. You should pass *method names* as arguments for the `Bind` method. Instead, you make a *method call* (this causes the bound methods to be executed during UI construction). To fix it, you have to leave out the parentheses. The last two lines of your listing should become this:

```
menubar.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, onDocClick, documentation)
menubar.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, onAboutClick, about)
```

I tried out your code, and BrtH was right, I was not successul with binding from the menubar, you should bind events from the `wx.Frame` instance instead.
Your complete, runnable example now looks like this:

```
import wx

def onDocClick(evt):
   message = wx.MessageBox("did it work?","Question",wx.YES_NO)

def onAboutClick(evt):
   print "clicked"

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None,title="RVR GUI",size=(315,490))
frame.Show()
panel = wx.Panel(frame,-1,size=(315,490))

menubar = wx.MenuBar()
fileMenu = wx.Menu()
documentation = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW,"Documentation")
about = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"About")
menubar.Append(fileMenu,'File')

frame.SetMenuBar(menubar)
frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,onDocClick,documentation)
frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,onAboutClick,about)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you Phineas, with your advice I am now able to get that code to work as planned! You rock!

Answer (score -1):

You are binding to the wrong thing. Bind to the frame instead. Try `frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU,onDocClick(),documentation)`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, and your right about that. However the second arg will still cause the function to be executed on interpretation. However once that was changed I had to do that so that I could actually receive the events.

Comment: yeah, because i noticed my error, I didn't see the obvious other error. My fault, sorry :(

Comment: Don't be sorry, without your comment I'd probably still be trying to figure out why nothing was happening when I clicked! :p